# Некорректное отображение вью

Tags: java, android, mobile

в сервисе показываю наполняю и делаю вьюху визибл, на тестовом девайсе вьюха нормально отображается, когда публикую в гугл плей и скачиваю, шрифта во вьюхе меняется на белый или даже исчезает шрифт, это на 6-ой версии. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Что за "вьюха"?

Comment: обычная View, в которую заинфлейтил лайаут